# Ignore space for importing to MySQL in java

Tags: java, mysql, json

I am using java. I have these json data with 2 space each other.

```
{"created_at":"Mon Jun 01 09:59:50 +0000 2015","id":605312790992056324,"id_str":"605312790992056324"}


{"created_at":"Mon Jun 01 09:59:51 +0000 2015","id":605312794565713920,"id_str":"605312794565713920"}


{"created_at":"Mon Jun 01 09:59:51 +0000 2015","id":605312798445297664,"id_str":"605312798445297664"}


{"created_at":"Mon Jun 01 09:59:53 +0000 2015","id":605312806771146753,"id_str":"605312806771146753"}
```

then I import to MySQL but found these problems. It still can connect to db but cannot read space, I think. Anyone know how to add code for cope the 2 space? Thanks before. For 4 data it's okay, but I have a lot of data...

```
connection sucess
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\june1.json (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:680)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:674)
    at converter.Converter.ReadJSON(Converter.java:30)
    at converter.Converter.main(Converter.java:18)
```

Comment: read your exception message again please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is trying to write to C:/Users/june1.json and for some reason cannot do that. The Windows system directory may not allow files (but only user directories. So try C:/Users/nizar/june1.json or such.

Or:

```
File outFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/june1.json");
```