# Insert value into specific column from another table with groupby

Tags: mysql, datetime, insert, where-clause

I am using MySQL. I want to insert value's result from groupby of datetime to specific column (using where, maybe). Let say:
I have two tables (a, b). In table a, I want to get how many total records during a hour (which I have datetime column), then the result will insert into table b, but in specific ID (there is already exist ID's value).

This is my error code:

```
INSERT INTO b(value)
WHERE ID=15
SELECT DAY COUNT(*)
FROM a
WHERE date >= '2015-09-19 00:00:00' AND date < '2015-09-19 00:59:59'
GROUP BY DAY(date),HOUR(date);";
```

Is that possible I make a query from this case?
Thank you very much for any reply!

Comment: that is an update join pattern, or at least an update stmt. Not an insert. You can do an upsert, but I won't go there

Comment: okay, nice clue. I will find the solution. (however, I need the solution from here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Schema

```
create table tA
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    theDate datetime not null,
    -- other stuff
    key(theDate) -- make it snappy fast
);

create table tB
(   myId int primary key,   -- by definition PK is not null
    someCol int not null
);

-- truncate table tA;
-- truncate table tB;

insert tA(theDate) values
('2015-09-19'),
('2015-09-19 00:24:21'),
('2015-09-19 07:24:21'),
('2015-09-20 00:00:00');

insert tB(myId,someCol) values (15,-1); --    (-1) just for the heck of it
insert tB(myId,someCol) values (16,-1); --    (-1) just for the heck of it
```

### The Query

```
update tB
set someCol=(select count(*) from tA where theDate between '2015-09-19 00:00:00' and '2015-09-19 00:59:59')
where tB.myId=15;
```

### The Results

```
select * from tB;
+------+---------+
| myId | someCol |
+------+---------+
|   15 |       2 |
|   16 |      -1 |
+------+---------+
```

**only myId=15 is touched.**

Comment: great, check mark it green as Answered. Also the [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30668522/1816093) you asked a while back

Comment: you make it a green check mark under the number 0 upper left by my answer. Thank you sir. Happy trails :)

Comment: anytime cak you know where to find us :)