# Update table from aggregate of another table

Tags: mysql

Consider these two tables

```
TABLE A
id name surname
1  test  test2
2  test  test2

Table B
id name surname count
1  test test2
```

What I want to do is, for a given id in Table B, I will count the number of rows that have same name and surname combination from Table A, and update count column of Table B

I have tried this

```
UPDATE Table_A, TABLE_B
SET TABLE_B.count=COUNT(TABLE_A.id)
WHERE TABLE_A.name=TABLE_B.name AND TABLE_A.surname=TABLE_B.surname
AND TABLE_B.id=1
```

But I am getting `Invalid use of group function` error.

What is the correct syntax to achieve this?

My question is different from [Update row with data from another row in the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574434) because that question doesn't address counting rows of the other table. Moreover, that question doesn't use two different tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update row with data from another row in the same table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574434/update-row-with-data-from-another-row-in-the-same-table)

Comment: You would probably be better to calculate the aggregate separately, store it in a variable, then update with that variable.

Comment: I showed an answer for that sort of thing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32670593)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert value into specific column from another table with groupby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670306/insert-value-into-specific-column-from-another-table-with-groupby)